# Trying to configure Logstash to use a proxy with LS_JAVA_OPTS but it doesn't seem to work

Tags: proxy, logstash

Elastic is running on a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM in Azure.
VM1: Running in Hyper-V on my workstation with Windows Server 2012 R2.  No Proxy
VM2: Setup in a protected domain with Windows Server 2012 R2; Requires a proxy

My Logstash config (my.config) has this output definition:

```
elasticsearch 
{ 
    host => "myhost.cloudapp.net"
    cluster => "mycluster"
    document_type => "%{type}"
    index => "%{index}_%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    template_name => "%{index}"
    document_id => "%{id}"
    protocol => "http"
}
```

VM1 can load data into the Elastic Search host just fine
I zipped the logstash folder from VM1 and copied it into VM2 and extracted it.  I then created a start.bat file which was placed in \logstash\bin

```
cls
SET JAVA_HOME=D:\JDK
SET LS_JAVA_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy.mydomain.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
logstash.bat agent -f my.conf
```

When running this on VM2, the following is produced in the command prompt window:

```
io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated
Failed to install template: connect timed out {:level=>:error}
Logstash startup completed
Got error to send bulk of actions: connect timed out {:level=>:error}
Failed to flush outgoing items {:outgoing_count=>1, :exception=>#<Manticore::Timeout: connect timed out>, 
:backtrace=>["D:/LogStash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.4.1-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:35:in `initialize'", 
"org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in `call'", 
"D:/LogStash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.4.1-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:61:in `call'", 
"D:/LogStash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.4.1-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:225:in `call_once'", 
"D:/LogStash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.4.1-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:128:in `code'", 
"D:/LogStash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.12/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/manticore.rb:71:in `perform_request'", 
"org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in `call'", 
"D:/LogStash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.12/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:190:in `perform_request'", 
"D:/LogStash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.12/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/manticore.rb:54:in `perform_request'", 
"D:/LogStash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.12/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:119:in `perform_request'", 
"D:/LogStash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-api-1.0.12/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/bulk.rb:80:in `bulk'", 
"D:/LogStash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-1.0.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/protocol.rb:103:in `bulk'", 
"D:/LogStash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-1.0.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:505:in `submit'", 
"D:/LogStash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-1.0.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:529:in `flush'", 
"D:/LogStash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.20/lib/stud/buffer.rb:219:in `buffer_flush'", 
"org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1341:in `each'", 
"D:/LogStash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.20/lib/stud/buffer.rb:216:in `buffer_flush'", 
"D:/LogStash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.20/lib/stud/buffer.rb:112:in `buffer_initialize'", 
"org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1511:in `loop'", 
"D:/LogStash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.20/lib/stud/buffer.rb:110:in `buffer_initialize'"], :level=>:warn}
```

I tried this with Logstash v1.5.0.  I updated the logstash version in VM2 to v1.5.2, but that does not seem to help.

I went into the "Configure Java" GUI and setup the proxy under Network Settings and that didn't help.  I'm also using JDK version 1.8.0_45-b15.

I also tried using the http output plugin, which also did not work.  Here's the logstash config for that:

```
 http
 {
      http_method => "post"
      url => "http://myhost.cloudapp.net/myindex/mytype"
 }
```

The error I was getting with this is (only copied the exception message below).

```
:response=>nil, :exception=>#<Errno::EBADF: Bad file descriptor - Bad file descriptor>
```

It is probably worth mentioning that I can use Mozilla and Internet Explorer to get to the Marvel Sense plugin and can issue requests to the Elastic Search cluster.  Here's an example request header from fiddler:

```
GET http://myhost.cloudapp.net:9200/_cat/indices?_=1436330129174 HTTP/1.1
Referer: http://myhost.cloudapp.net:9200/_plugin/marvel/sense/index.html
Accept: text/plain, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: xirtes.cloudapp.net:9200
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
```

ANY help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Found the JVM monitor and verified that when setting the LS_JAVA_OPTS the value is not being appended to the VM arguments.

I am now setting the JAVA_OPTS variable in my start.bat.  Using the JVM monitor, my "VM Arguments" system variable contains my proxy info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spoke with the kind folks at elastic search and a they confirmed that LogStash doesn't support a forwarding proxy as of right now.  However, a new request has been made to add this functionality ( https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/issues/199 )

They suggested using a reverse proxy in the meantime (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

Try:
    output {
      elasticsearch {
      index => "%{index}_%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      host => "myhost.cloudapp.net"
      port => "9200"
      protocol => http
      idle_flush_time => 1
      flush_size => 5000
     }
    }

Comment: This didn't seem to have any effect.